Powershell and Invoke-RestMethod
I am trying to access the Snipe IT API and check if an asset exists by its serial number. I have a function that will use Invoke-RestMethod and should return a JSON message. It is my understanding that Invoke-RestMethod will convert it automatically to a PSObject and therefor i should just be able to access it via a property.
Function Check-AssetExists {
param (
    [string]$serialNumber
)

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $apiToken"
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$snipeItURL/api/v1/hardware/byserial/$serialNumber" -Method Get -Headers $headers
return $response
}

The returned JSON should be the following if there are no assets.
{
  "status": "error",
  "messages": "Asset does not exist."
}

The code to call is below.
$deviceSerialNumber = Get-SerialNumber
$assetCheckResponse = Check-AssetExists -serialNumber $deviceSerialNumber

write-host $assetCheckResponse.status

If i run the last line without status i get @{total=1; rows=System.Object[]} so it is an object but is i run the last line as above its blank, i.e i get nothing returned
I've just put a breakpoint in and hovered over the response and got the following. I presume it isn't working becuase its not actually in the payload but the error is outside of it?

API Endpoint documentation: https://snipe-it.readme.io/reference/hardware-by-serial

without write-host it is still the same

so the API isnt giving the response you expected. but you should add the API documentation or how you're determining that the API response should've been like the Json you've added in your question

I have put a breakpoint in and updated my post. Also the API documentation is here https://snipe-it.readme.io/reference/api-overview

I don't see an error in your code. What you can try is use Invoke-WebRequest instead of Invoke-RestMethod so you can see the Json as is without being converted to an object: (Invoke-WebRequest "$snipeItURL/api/v1/hardware/byserial/$serialNumber" -Method Get -Headers $headers).Content and see if it is exactly as it is expected

I guess $deviceSerialNumber, isn't a plain string (maybe even an array). Check: $deviceSerialNumber.PSTypeNames and try $assetCheckResponse = Check-AssetExists -serialNumber "$deviceSerialNumber"

For the response, try using the unary comma to prefent the (appearent) datatable to unroll in a single row: return ,$response (or just ,$response).

In your screenshot your code says write-host $repsonse.status with response having the “p” and “s” the wrong way round. I’m presuming the variable with a typo has a value from a previous iteration of your code - if you restart your IDE it’ll stop outputting @{total=1; rows=System.Object[]} and show an empty string instead because the variable will no longer exist, and if you then fix the typo you’ll get the expected status output when there are no items in the response…

After changing the request to a WebRequest i can see the JSON that is being returned. The content is: {"status":"error","messages":"Asset does not exist.","payload":null}

Sorry for the late response, I noted this issue during my holidays as a interesting PowerShell problem which could be related to a known gotcha or bug, but now I am in the position to test it, I am not able to reproduce it against the Snipe-It Demo api.
This works for me in both Windows PowerShell en PowerShell (core):
function Check-AssetExists {
    param (
        [string]$serialNumber
    )

    $headers = @{
        Authorization = 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZTU2MDc0MjVmYjM5YTEwYjFjNTZlZTAxMTBmZDk4ZjQ0ZjVjODMzYjcxZWVhYjZlNDk1NGMwOThlY2YzMzU2MDY4Mzg4MmFhMDMzOTAzNzciLCJpYXQiOjE2MzI4NjU5MTgsIm5iZiI6MTYzMjg2NTkxOCwiZXhwIjoyMjY0MDIxNTE4LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.LgGVzyH67IRhXvccHd4j2Dn6TDuIuQTBoo30_wD9jPehy8v_h0xBmE1-dOUBRJyeJOI8B4gwPeALsWaudpGj9Lb5qWAtKV7eYtH9IYQKoLF_iHgOGXnAUcNwID6zBU_YyLNSI6gp8zjutLJias33CBLsHy5ZRNpxVibVrZouJ_HjYuIYbtZyLus-KFFeibtZoPiTWOeHhQFD37MR6ifx4dBqT37fN-xDS99mONtrkAplEIou5aSO1oZ4IlJIPCUyA1lixPgpn1YU7PxiBDZp1teeugD0WEmrAqxRS2I0bH4qPsuTsrVXS_lo87Sf5LBGLW7lGHKqyYH6J47OZOM0K-SrxLKtE1ww8jyLBgnnxH0lJHRLCBiwUnL5ZGTUmiOysUA-wSJ6s78o8Pc-ec6bpBvAlelHdiQ-wslE7gzEJDptbejFg-75b_CEwgJYh7J2D18ul6Qu5EFCUEgt033mm04dgVk0isWTDt6EW5ZvTo5Qhr1LY0YnEIXCTqIRN-BSQjL55sZaCrtwR_21bnBGgniyI5MRDYblFawVmFKroeClCpSjBo9vi66akdD5hjpvx67RL3r33BZQhEXmPifUPNH5wP_U-IHGFUD99TJk2c1awF0RASveZRLSunbJb1x6hGAVUaIvQV4r2quWzXqYyKLph9kGTyJYrb6iJtH5smE'
        Accept = 'application/json'
    }

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://develop.snipeitapp.com/api/v1/hardware/byserial/$serialNumber" -Method Get -Headers $headers
    return $response
}

$assetCheckResponse = Check-AssetExists -serialNumber 123
$assetCheckResponse

status messages              payload
------ --------              -------
error  Asset does not exist.

$assetCheckResponse.status

error

